# How to ignore br tags in an XPATH statement?

Tags: xml, xpath

Need an XPATH for article text, which has many br tags and it should be not considered and pick the previous line before the last one. But in few cases because of extra br tags it doesn't work.

```
//div[@id="artText"]/text()[last()-1]
```

Here before the last line there are many br tags and it is not consistent across the site. How can I ignore the br tags?

The xml input is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='artTt' style='font-size: 12pt; line-height: 150%;' itemprop='articleBody'>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class='center_image' style='width:90%;' originw='198'>
      <img src='//file.71_1519345637.jpg' border='0' hspace='0' vspace='0' width='100%' alt='???? ?? ???' />
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />[? ???? &amp; ???? ? ??? ??]</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post the input xml ?

Comment: <div id='artTt' style='font-size: 12pt; line-height: 150%;' itemprop='articleBody'>
<br><br> <div class='center_image' style='width:90%;' originw='198'><img src='//file.71_1519345637.jpg' border='0' hspace='0' vspace='0' width='100%' alt='???? ?? ???'></div>
<br><br>
           <br><br>
           [? ???? & ???? ? ??? ??] 
           </div>
          </div>

Comment: That's not even valid XML.

Comment: Please add your XML (1) to the question itself, (2) in a formatted block. Question updates are not very readable in comments, and questions will often close if updates are not added.

Comment: Like Markus noted the provided document is not a real xml document. Just plain html. So the first step could be to get an xml-ished version of the input

Comment: Sorry. Actually i want to extract the previous line from article body and not consider br tags. When used text()[last()-1] it gives empty if br tags are present. So need a xpath to ignore All br tags and get the previous line of  article text